# Searching a vector/data table backwards in R

Tags: r, search, dataframe, data.table, na

Basically, I have a very large data frame/data table and I would like to search a column for the first, and closest, `NA` value which is less than my current index position.

For example, let's say I have a data frame `DF` as follows:

```
INDEX | KEY   |   ITEM
----------------------
 1    |  10   |    AAA
 2    |  12   |    AAA
 3    |  NA   |    AAA
 4    |  18   |    AAA
 5    |  NA   |    AAA
 6    |  24   |    AAA
 7    |  29   |    AAA
 8    |  31   |    AAA
 9    |  34   |    AAA
```

From this data frame we have an `NA` value at index 3 and at index 5. Now, let's say we start at index 8 (which has `KEY` of 31). I would like to search the column `KEY` backwards such that the moment it finds the first instance of `NA` the search stops, and the index of the NA value is returned.

I know there are ways to find all `NA` values in a vector/column (for example, I can use `which(is.na(x))` to return the index values which have `NA`) but due to the sheer size of the data frame I am working and due to the large number of iterations that need to be performed this is a very inefficient way of doing it. One method I thought of doing is creating a kind of "do while" loop and it does seem to work, but this again seems quite inefficient since it needs to perform calculations each time (and given that I need to do over 100,000 iterations this does not look like a good idea).

Is there a fast way of searching a column backwards from a particular index such that I can find the index of the closest `NA` value?

Comment: `Position(is.na, head(dat$KEY, 8), right=TRUE)` maybe?

Comment: possibly `max(which(is.na(df[df$INDEX <= 8, ]$KEY)))` ?

Comment: The `Position` method is something I have not yet considered so I'll try that and check the system time to see its efficiency, thanks! Regarding using the `max(which(is.na` though, I have been using that method up until now but it is extremely inefficient since the function must scan through the entire column and locate each `NA` value before it returns the largest index. Ideally, I would like to search the column backwards from my index position such that the moment it encounters the first `NA` value the search stops.

Comment: @ThePlowKing - you must have some seriously large data. Even on 30M records @SymbolixAU's solution runs in a few seconds for me. Admittedly, `Position()` is markedly quicker, but not an outrageous difference.

Comment: The data is very large, but it's also the number of iterations that slows it down a lot. The calculation I'm performing will be used several times in a single iteration and the number of iterations is at least going to be over 100,000 for one setting and will be several million in other settings, so I'm basically trying to do everything I can to speed things up. Up until now I've been using @SymbolixAU solution, but I need something better since things have become far more complex for me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not do a forward-fill of the NA indexes once, so that you can then look up the most recent NA for any row in future:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df = df %>%
    mutate(last_missing = if_else(is.na(KEY), INDEX, as.integer(NA))) %>%
    fill(last_missing)
```

Output:

```
> df
  INDEX KEY ITEM last_missing
1     1  10  AAA           NA
2     2  12  AAA           NA
3     3  NA  AAA            3
4     4  18  AAA            3
5     5  NA  AAA            5
6     6  24  AAA            5
7     7  29  AAA            5
8     8  31  AAA            5
9     9  34  AAA            5
```

Now there's no need to recalculate every time you need the answer for a given row. There may be more efficient ways to do the forward fill, but I think exploring those is easier than figuring out how to optimise the backward search.

Comment: That's a really clever idea, it never occurred to me and it's so easy to implement as well! Thanks for that!

Comment: Or another option is with `zoo` `with(df, na.locf((NA^!is.na(KEY))*INDEX, na.rm = FALSE))`

Comment: What's `as.integer(NA)`? Why not `NA_integer_`?