# Searching Two Columns in a Data Frame in R

Tags: r, search, dataframe, data.table

I have a question about searching for values in R, it is actually a bit similar to a question which was posted yesterday (as given over here: [Searching a vector/data table backwards in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44876579/searching-a-vector-data-table-backwards-in-r?noredirect=1#comment76731702_44876579)) except I think my problem is a bit more complicated (and also the opposite of what I want to do), and since I'm very new to R I'm not too sure how to solve this problem.

I have a data frame similar to one given below, and I wish to find a previous index value to my current one where the `Times` column is different to my current time and the `Midquote` column does not have an `NA` value.

```
Index               Times    |    Midquote
                -----------------------------
   1            10:30:45.58  |    5.319
   2            10:30:45.93  |    5.323
   3            10:30:45.104 |    5.325
   4            10:30:45.127 |    5.322
   5            10:30:45.188 |    5.325
   6            10:30:45.188 |    NA
   7            10:30:45.212 |    NA
   8            10:30:45.231 |    5.321
   9            10:30:45.231 |    5.321
```

If we start at the bottom of the data frame  and take this to be the 'current' time, this is found to be at index 9 and which has a `Times` value of `10:30:45.231` and `Midquote` value of `5.321`, then if I want to find the first index where the time is different to my current time, we see this is found to be index 7, which has a time of `10:30:45.212` (since index 8 has the same time). But we also see that at index 7 the `Midquote` value is `NA` so I now have to check the data frame again. Index 6 again has a different time (i.e. `10:30:45.188` ) but it also has an `NA` value again in the `Midquote` column, so moving up again to index 5 we see that the `Times` column has a different time to my current time (i.e. `10:30:45.188` again)  and that the `Midquotes`  value is `5.325`.

Therefore, since at index 5 the time is `10:30:45.188` (which is different to my current time which was `10:30:45.231`) and since the `Midquote` value at index 5 is not `NA`, I wish to obtain the output '5' since it is the index value which fulfills both criteria.

My question is, is there a good way of doing this? I am sorry if this is an easy question, I am very new to R and I don't know much about working with data frames...

EDIT: I would also like to do it preferably without adding another column to the data frame (as is given in the top answer of the link I mentioned above), if that is possible

Comment: Can you show the expected output?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by that? I would like to be able to obtain index 5 from the data frame if that is what you are asking, since the `Time` is different to my current time (since I am starting at the very bottom of the data frame) and the `Midquote` is not `NA`

Comment: Show what  you want the data to look like, i.e. what the "answer" to your question looks like for your example data. It helps if you show the answer for all relevant rows in the data (not just index 9), because that can make the exact rules clearer.

Comment: Sorry about that, I will edit my topic now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood it correctly, please check if this is the output you are expecting.

```
ind<-function(t,df){
    ind<-t
    while(t>1){
       t=t-1
        if((df$Times[t]!=df$Times[ind]) && (!is.na(df$Midquote[t]))){
            return(t)
        }
    }
}
sapply((nrow(data):1),FUN = ind,data)

#[[1]]
#[1] 5

#[[2]]
#[1] 5

#[[3]]
#[1] 5

#[[4]]
#[1] 4

#[[5]]
#[1] 4

#[[6]]
#[1] 3

#[[7]]
#[1] 2

#[[8]]
#[1] 1

#[[9]]
#NULL
```

The output series corresponds to the associated index for your data.frame starting from the last row.

Explanation: `ind` takes the value of row number as the **current row**, while `t` takes value starting from `ind-1` to 1. `df` takes the entire data.frame as input and then `while` loop is used to check if time and midquote value of  `df$Times[t]` and `df$Midquote[t]` satisfy the required conditions. If  yes they return the index else the loop continues until it reaches the first row.

Without using `sapply` for a particular current row:

```
 ind(9,df)
 [1] 5
```

Comment: Thanks, this does seem to be the sort of thing I'm looking for :) Could you explain what the sapply function is needed for though? I tried entering it in with the function but it didn't work properly and I'm not too familiar with what it does

Comment: sapply is generally used for looping through a vector or list in R without using the for loop...Since, I assumed that you would need the indexes for each row element I used sapply.

Comment: @reallybadstatdude added explanation and corrected a typo in the function.   Hope it works for you now.

Comment: @reallybadstatdude what is your expected output? could you explain?

Comment: Yes, obtaining 5 is the expected output :) At present I have to wait a little bit before I can test it out my data though so I cannot yet properly test out all the different methods people have discussed until I actually get it (which should be sometime in the next few hours...). Additionally, I don't wish to accept an answer until my reputation is up a little more since I wish to upvote everyone who has replied so far

Comment: Thanks, so far I'm liking yours the most since it appears to be pretty fast while also being easy to understand. I just have one final question: Say I wish to do the reverse (i.e. find the _next_ time to my current time while also making sure the `Midquote` column doesn't have `NA`) then that means for the `ind` function you wrote I only need to change the `t=t-1` to `t=t+1` right? (Sorry if this is trivial, this is all new to me)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148369/discussion-between-tushar-and-reallybadstatdude).

Answer (score 2):

Working with dates is tough especially with fractional seconds.
If you could convert the times to doubles it would be easier to work with. 
Assuming your 'Times' are in order you could use this

```
library(magrittr)
which(df$Times < df[9,1] & !is.na(df$Midquote)) %>% max()
```

The `which` gives a vector of the 'Index' where 'Times' are less than that in 9 AND the 'Midquote' is not NA. The `%>%` sends the vector to `max()` which gives the highest value. This is pretty inelegant, but will get the job done.

Answer (score 1):

`Data.table` solution, 1 line.

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(Index = 1:9,
                 Times = c( '10:30:45.58', '10:30:45.93','10:30:45.104','10:30:45.127','10:30:45.188','10:30:45.188','10:30:45.212','10:30:45.231','10:30:45.231' ),
                 Midquote = c('5.319','5.323','5.325','5.322','5.325',NA,NA,'5.321','5.321')
                )

> dt[ Times != Times[.N] & !is.na(Midquote), max(Index) ]
[1] 5
```

**EDIT**

To remove the Index column you have (at least) two options

```
dt2 <- data.table(Times = c( '10:30:45.58', '10:30:45.93','10:30:45.104','10:30:45.127','10:30:45.188','10:30:45.188','10:30:45.212','10:30:45.231','10:30:45.231' ),
                  Midquote = c('5.319','5.323','5.325','5.322','5.325',NA,NA,'5.321','5.321'))


# Option 1 - create an id column on the fly (unfortunately data.table recalculate .I after evaluating the "where" clause... so you need to save it)
dt2[, cbind(.SD, id=.I)][ Times != Times[.N] & !is.na(Midquote), max(id) ]

# Option 2 - simply check the last position of where your condition is met
dt2[, max(which(Times != Times[.N] & !is.na(Midquote))) ]
```

**NB** You can't do `nrow` because you can have, say, the 1st, 2nd, and 4th records matching your condition, and `nrow` would give you 3, which is wrong because the 3rd row does not match.

**EDIT 2** *(option 3 is not **correct**)*

```
dt3 <- data.table(Times = c( '10:30:45.58', '10:30:45.93','10:30:45.104','10:30:45.127','10:30:45.188','10:30:45.188','10:30:45.212','10:30:45.231','10:30:45.231' ),
                  Midquote = c('5.319','5.323', NA,'5.322','5.325', NA, NA,'5.321','5.321'))


# Option 1 - create an id column on the fly (unfortunately data.table recalculate .I after evaluating the "where" clause... so you need to save it)
dt3[, cbind(.SD, id=.I)][ Times != Times[.N] & !is.na(Midquote), max(id) ]
[1] 5

# Option 2 - simply check the last position of where your condition is met
dt3[, max(which(Times != Times[.N] & !is.na(Midquote))) ]
[1] 5

# Option 3 - good luck with this
nrow(dt3[Times != Times[.N] & !is.na(Midquote)])
[1] 4
```

Comment: This does seem to be quite efficient, but is there any way to do this without creating a new column? Additionally, and please correct me if I am wrong, but from what I can tell the function appears to moving forward through the data table rather than moving backward through the data table. Since I need to move backward through the data table this may not be appropriate (but of course I might be interpreting it the wrong way)

Comment: Sorry please disregard my previous comment, I think I understand why you used the max() function now. I was just wondering, would this be an alternative to what you wrote: nrow((df2[Times != Times[i] & !is.na(Midquote)])) ? This way I don't need to create a new Index column. Note that by `i` in the `Times[i]` code above I'm just referring to a general index value (since the index can change and may not necessarily be the last value of a data table)

Comment: thanks for that, just one last question: You mention that `nrow` cannot be used, but I don't fully understand what you mean by your example. For the dataset example here using `nrow` seems to work (since it returns 5) so I was wondering if you could very briefly explain it in a little more details if it's not too much trouble